# App that permanently shows data in notification center

Tags: ios, notificationcenter

I would like to create an application that would show data in the iOS notification center permanently, like the built-in Weather or Stocks apps.

Is that possible? Does anyone have a clue how?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with the official SDK. It has been done in the jailbreak community though through use of Private APIs.

Comment: that's what i was afraid of, i would like to do that with official SDK

Comment: Then unfortunately, as of now (6.0.1) you cannot do what you are looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. All you may show are Push Notifications or local Notifications. You cannot influence the appearance at all. Stocks & Weather & Twitter/Facebook widgets are directly from apple and built into iOS.